# Windows (x86) Assembly Append Null Terminator To Inputted String

Tags: windows, string, assembly, x86, append

I am currently trying to append a null terminator to an(a?) user inputted string:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

WriteFile PROTO STDCALL:DWORD, :PTR, :DWORD, :PTR DWORD, :PTR OVERLAPPED
ReadFile  PROTO STDCALL:DWORD, :PTR, :DWORD, :PTR DWORD, :PTR OVERLAPPED
GetStdHandle PROTO STDCALL:DWORD

.data
    buff            DB 100h DUP(?)
    stdInHandle     DWORD 0
    bytesRead       DWORD ?

.code
    start:
            ;read string from stdin
            INVOKE GetStdHandle, -10
            MOV stdInHandle, eax
            INVOKE ReadFile, stdInHandle, BYTE PTR[buff], 100, ADDR bytesRead, 0

            ;append null terminator on CR,LF
            MOV eax, bytesRead
            MOV edx, BYTE PTR[buff]
            SUB eax, 2
            AND BYTE PTR [eax+edx], 0
            RET
    END start
```

It refuses to assemble at `MOV edx, BYTE PTR[buff]` and gives me an error:
`error: Invalid combination of opcode and operands (or wrong CPU setting).`

So I'm assuming I cannot `MOV` the value of `BYTE PTR[buff]` into register edx. So I can't even begin to test if this method of trying to apply a `NULL` terminator to a string will even work.

My question is, what is wrong with the above code (should I use a different register instead of edx?)

What is the best way to apply a `NULL` terminator to the string?

Comment: `and` with immediate 0 is crazy.  Use `mov byte ptr [eax + edx], 0`.  There's no reason to use an instruction that loads the old value, just do a write-only `mov`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so common that the MASM32 runtime supplies this functionality as part of its runtime. All you need to do is include the relevant code:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
```

Then use the `StripLF` function as so:

```
invoke StripLF, addr buff
```

To fix your current problem (if you want to do it manually) , you need to move the address of `buff` to `edx` instead.

```
mov edx, offset buff
```

Comment: I see, thank you. I am trying to learn it manually just out of interest. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move a byte value into a dword sized register. You either need to use a byte sized register such as `dl`, or zero-extend it with `movzx`. As you are working with bytes, I suggest you go with the first option.

Comment: Well that solved one problem; now t's saying that `AND BYTE PTR [eax+dl], 0` specifies an invalid address, I have a feeling that I'm really heading in the wrong direction with this.

Comment: In addressing you can't mix different sized registers, in this case you need to zero-extend the offset into the entire `edx`.

Comment: Hmm, doing that seems to give me an access violation and the program just crashes... According to my debugger the Access Violation is raised immediately after entering a value and jumps to: `AND BYTE PTR [eax+edx], 0` and crashes after that step. According to my debugger the value of `EDX` remains `0` throughout as well. Sorry if I'm being annoying. I'm just genuinely confused.

Comment: You have solved his immediate problem but missed the bigger picture of why his code does not work.

Comment: You are dereferencing `buff`, `edx` should contain the *address*.

Answer (score 2):

When I had to create methods for strings without using anything from good ole Irvine, I got the length of the string, incremented what the length returned as (you need to include an extra +1 for the null-terminator) by 1, and then added 0h to the end of the string where the pointer was where the counter is.

```
MOV     EAX, SIZEOF lpSourceString + 1      ; Get the string length of string, add 1 to include null-terminator
INVOKE allocMem, EAX                    ; Allocate memory for a target to copy to
LEA     ESI, [lpSourceString]           ; put source address in ESI
MOV     EDI, EAX                        ; copy the dest address to another register we can increment
MOV     ECX, SIZEOF lpSourceString      ; Set up loop counter
```

We have the size of the string. Now we can add the null-terminate to it. To do that, we need to make sure that we have a pointer looking at the end of the string. So if we have a method that returns a string in EAX, EAX needs to point to the start of the string (so we leave the `allocMem` unmodified, instead incrementing a copy in EDI). Let's say that we are putting characters in a string:

```
nextByte:                   ; Jump label, get the next byte in the string until ECX is 0
MOV     DL, [ESI]           ; Get the next character in the string
MOV     [EDI], DL           ; Store the byte at the position of ESI
INC     ESI                 ; Move to next char in source
INC     EDI                 ; INCrement EDI by 1
loop nextByte               ; Re-loop to get next byte

MOV     byte ptr[EDI], 0h   ; Add null-terminator to end of string

; EAX holds a pointer to the start of the dynamically-allocated
; 0-terminated copy of lpSourceString
```

MOV requires the `byte ptr` size specifier because neither the `[EDI]` memory operand nor the `0` immediate operand would imply a size for the operation.  The assembler wouldn't know if you meant a byte, word, or dword store.

I have this in my MASM, but I use a `String_length` stdcall method I had written due to a class requirement.

Comment: Instead of copying 1 byte at a time with the `loop` instruction, `rep movsb` to copy ECX bytes from `[ESI]` to `[EDI]` is probably a win for strings more than maybe 8 to 16 bytes long on current CPUs.  (Or `rep movsd` if you know the size is a multiple of 4). It has startup overhead, but then copies efficiently.  On future CPUs (like IceLake), the fast short-rep CPU feature will presumably make it very good even for short copies. But really for compile-time-constant size, the most efficient current solution would be to inline some dword copies. Or at least use `dec ecx/jnz` to loop efficiently

Comment: Also, use `MOV  EAX, SIZEOF lpSourceString + 1` to avoid a runtime `inc`, and use `mov edi, EAX` instead of LEA to copy a register.  Or since you're *not* using `rep movsb`, use `[EAX]` as the destination addressing mode inside the loop instead of copying to EDI at all.

Comment: Actually, you're returning a pointer to the end, not start, of a 0-terminated string?  That doesn't seem right.  And you aren't incrementing ESI inside the loop, so you're actually doing `memset(dst, src[0], len)`, repeating the first byte `n` times.  That's a bug if this is supposed to create a dynamically-allocated implicit-length copy of an explicit-length string.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Cordes. My assignments are very restrictive so I was not allowed to use rep or memset so I'm not very knowledgeable in them. The SIZEOF part, I honestly had not considered doing SIZEOF and adding 1. I will use that in the near future (and will edit the above to incorporate that).

Comment: I think you missed my 3rd comment: you're not actually copying the string, you're broadcasting its first character, because you forgot to `inc esi` inside the loop.  Or you could use indexed addressing modes counting an index up to `SIZEOF lpSourceString + 1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, I did miss your 3rd comment. I had not realized I'd forgotten that, thank you.

Comment: Ok, now you are copying.  But you're returning a pointer to the terminating `0` byte, not to the start of the string.  Probably remove the `MOV     EAX, EDI` at the end, and use `mov byte ptr [edi], 0` to store the terminating zero after the loop.  (Because EAX still holds the malloc return value.)

Comment: @PeterCordes oh shoot, you are correct. This is what I get for copy-n-pasta snippets. Aiiiiish. Correction added.

Comment: I made some more cleanups for you, and improved (IMO) the comments to explain why, and talk about the semantic meaning, not the architectural state.